# GA Management API Update Users Custom Dimension value, Goal Tracking strategy

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

So Let's assume I have a custom event inside my APP and I push custom dimension that has a certain value,

Is it possible through GA Management API to get that Custom Dimension by the value and then update it to the new value?

What I'm trying to achieve is, I want to track when user do his first paying process inside the app and to compare how many users that hit the first Goal (Signup) ended up paying it, what's the best way to do that thru the GA?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot update historical data in Google Analytics.

You can track userId, sessionId and hitTimestamp information as custom dimensions and work on it: https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/improve-data-collection-with-four-custom-dimensions/